# How to Give 'PickFolder' dialogue a title

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing some code in which the user will need to pick both a source folder and destination folder using:

```
Set SourceFolder = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

Set TargetFolder = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
```

Is there a way to give the folder selector dialogue a heading so that I don't have to use a message box or something to tell the user which folder they are picking each time?

Comment: No - there are no arguments you can pass to `PickFolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in Outlook Object Model. You can either

a. Create your own form with the required functionality
b. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDOSelectFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSelectFoldersDialog.htm) object, which allows to set the dialog caption (besides other things):

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set SelectFoldersDialog = Session.GetSelectFoldersDialog
SelectFoldersDialog.Caption = "Please select your favorite folder"
if SelectFoldersDialog.Display Then
  set Folder = SelectFoldersDialog.SelectedFolder
  MsgBox "selected folder: " & Folder.Name
End If
```